# iPhone App Development - Audio Queue Recording

Tags: iphone

I am currently working on an App which needs to get some data from the microphone. I have read through some resources on the Internet and believe that Audio Queue is a good library to do it.

I only need to get an array which stores the microphone input data, and do not need to play it back.

Can anyone kindly give some hints on that? Greatly appreciated if a simple sample/essential code fragments can be given.

Answer (score 0):

Speak Here App given by the Apple can give you some idea.You can get the link here http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/index.html